# CefSharp XAML parse exception

Tags: c#, webrtc, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to work with CefSharp for video chat in my WPF application. So I added CefSharp using NuGet and added both CefSharp.Core and CefSharp.WPF. But when ever I try to run it gives me an error, both the code and error is added as image below.Please guide me.

[image: My Code]

This is the error I am getting.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

From the top screenshot I see that you are running with `Any CPU` as platform. You need that to either be `x86` or `x64`. See the **Please note:** comment under FAQ item #8 at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CefSharp_binaries for further.

The current CefSharp NuGet packages need that to pick up the right unmanaged CEF binaries.

In addition I'd recommend that you start with `CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf` from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: Is it a good idea to use CefSharp for video chat in WPF application, when I am using SignalR for text chat?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be a problem though I'm not familiar with SignalR. I think you could equal it with an application that could do both email and browse the web. Separate things. And sure text chat shouldn't take too much bandwidth from the video session ;)